# Socket.io How to emit from post request and listen from same server

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, socket.io

I want to send some data from post request to above socket.
Currently, I am doing emit to client from res.post, listen and emit again to socket from client. This is quite complicated.
Can I do it like this?

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("frompost", (body) => {
    console.log(body);
    socket.emit("toclient", body);
  });
});

app.post("/scan", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.body.wheelId;
  const token = req.body.token;
  const data = {};
  //VALIDATE TOKEN HERE
  io.sockets.emit("frompost", data);  // run listener above
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this best practice for authorization in Socket if you use api for authentication validation

In socket.io there is a middleware that can be used to validate, and we will use that middleware to validate tokens.

to sent token from client side in socket.io

```
let host "http://localhost:3000" // here is your host

let socket = io(host, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: "your token"
  }
})
```

and for server side

```
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server, Socket } = require('socket.io');
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
    
// set limit of data(1e6 = 1mb)
const io = new Server(server,{
  maxHttpBufferSize: 1e9
});

//socket io middleware

io.use((socket, next) => {
  const { authorization } = socket.handshake.headers;
  try {
    socket.user = jwt.verify(authorization, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
    next()
  } catch (error) {
    error.statusCode = 401
    next(error)
  }
});
```

When the user connects and an event occurs, this socket.io middleware checks the authentication token